# With DataJpaTest Repository Tests using MySQL, Hibernate doesn't set User to auto-increment in H2 DB

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, h2

I'm trying to test my Spring Boot repositories using DataJpaTest. I'm using MySQL, so all of my models are using IDENTITY for id generation:

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
```

But as you can see from the screenshot below, when I run my tests, Hibernate sets "generated by default as identity" for the ids of all of my models except for User and Property:

[image: screenshot of table generation]

This makes it so that I cannot create users (or properties) in my tests, since GenerationType.IDENTITY sets always sets the id to null before sending it to the db, which results in the following error:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? And, of course, more important than the why is what can I do to fix it? :)

**Update**
To simplify the problem a bit and provide different errors for different things I've tried...

My DataJpaTests are using H2, which I guess is automagically generating the db structure from the code. My real DB is MYSQL, which is generated in a separate project.

Scenario 1:
When I set GenerationType to IDENTITY, the live DB works, but the test DB gives me `could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]`.

Scenario 2:
When I set GenerationType to AUTO, the test DB works, but the live DB gives me `Table 'tablename.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist`.

Scenario 3:
Trying to make MYSQL work with GenerationType AUTO. I have found nothing in quite a lot of searching on how to tell Hibernate to default MYSQL to identity instead of table. I've found rather a lot saying to never use table and that overriding this is impossible without changing the Hibernate source code. This is a bunch of BS that makes me wonder what the Hibernate developers are smoking.

Scenario 4:
Trying to make H2 work with GenerationType IDENTITY. I've had some luck here with the following:

1. Putting `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=MYSQL` in a test.properties file.
2. Annotating my Test class with `@TestPropertySource(locations= "classpath:test.properties")` and `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)`

This gets rid of the null constraint error, but instead I'm now getting `The database returned no natively generated identity value`. Presumably, this is because, while the actual SQL code had auto_increment for the id, whatever magic is being used to generate the table for H2 isn't getting it there.

Addendum: The thing that is really frustrating about all of this is that it works totally fine for most of the tables. Out of the more than 20 tables in my DB, all but two of them auto generate and increment their ids just fine using IDENTITY. It makes no sense at all that some of them would work and some of them wouldn't.

Comment: *generated by default as identity* is not a MySQL or H2 clause I have ever seen. If that is the SQL being generated the something is wrong in your config.

Comment: *GenerationType.IDENTITY sets always sets the id to null before sending it to the db, which results in the following error.* For H2 you can set the value manually before saving without any issues. For other databases such as SQL server you need to [temporarily]  enable identity inserts.

Comment: @AlanHay Setting the value manually does not work. Still get null for Id. And I assumed that _generated by default as identity_ was a Hibernate message, not a SQL message. I know that's not SQL.

Comment: @AlanHay Okay, I guess that _generated by default as identity_ is how other dbs do it the MySQL way. And from what I see, that includes H2. I'm not sure why you think that isn't H2. Maybe just because that isn't the normal way to auto increment in H2?

Comment: Because H2 and MySQL would simply specify auto_increment for the column definition. Can you share your project on github or something because I have done this tens of times without any issue and it should be straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was another model with `@Table(name = "user")` as an annotation. That model also had the Id column defined, but without a generated value. With the conflict, Hibernate chose that one to define the id.

Answer (score -1):

MySql works better with

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

its also better because it produces auto-increment primary key in most RDBMS

Comment: Yeah, the team who built it told me they had to explicitly use IDENTITY for some reason, and since I'm not very familiar with Java, I didn't question it, but I guess I need to question it. :)

Comment: Yep, getting errors with AUTO for missing table hibernate_sequence.